# Dagger2 modules with mixed scopes

Tags: java, dependency-injection, scope, dagger, dagger-2

I am currently trying to set up dagger2 with a custom scope using subcomponents and I am having some trouble with the dagger compiler. More concretely, I have the following setup:

```
  @Qualifier @interface Foo {}
  @Qualifier @interface Baz {}
  @Scope @interface SomeScope {}

  @Module
  static class Amodule {
    @Provides
    @SomeScope
    @Foo
    String provideFoo(@Baz String baz) {
      return "foo" + baz;
    }

    @Provides
    @Baz
    String provideBaz() {
      return "baz";
    }
  }

  @Component(modules = Amodule.class)
  interface Acomponent {  
    @Baz String baz();
    Subcomp subcomp();
  }

  @SomeScope
  @Subcomponent
  interface Subcomp {
    @Foo String foo();
  }
```

Unfortunately, this is giving me the error:

```
Acomponent (unscoped) may not reference scoped bindings:
  @Component(modules = AModule.class)
  ^
      @Provides @SomeScope @Foo String Amodule.provideFoo(@Baz String)
```

I have managed to get things to work by splitting all the custom-scope bindings into a separate module, but I'm not sure why the setup above should not be possible. Also, in my case, the Foo and Baz objects are closely related, so I'd rather not split them into separate modules if it can be avoided.

Can anyone shed some light as to why the dagger compiler won't accept the example above? It seems like inside an `@SomeScope` subcomponent should be a valid place to expose a binding for `@Foo`. Am I misunderstanding something or could this be a limitation of the way the codegen is done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting has nothing to do with your Subcomponent yet.

You need to set your `Acomponent` to be of `@SomeScope`. You can not provide a different scope from an unscoped component. The [documentation](http://google.github.io/dagger/) states:

> Since Dagger 2 associates scoped instances in the graph with instances of component implementations, the components themselves need to declare which scope they intend to represent. For example, it wouldn't make any sense to have a @Singleton binding and a @RequestScoped binding in the same component because those scopes have different lifecycles and thus must live in components with different lifecycles.

Add the scope and this should work.

```
@SomeScope
@Component(modules = Amodule.class)
interface Acomponent {  
    @Baz String baz();
    Subcomp subcomp();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. However, one thing I'm wondering is how this generalizes to multiple scopes?

I'm asking because in my real example, I would like AComponent to also @Provide singleton scoped bindings for instance.

Also, I'm not quite sure how my original example contradicts the documentation: the AComponent would be unscoped, providing only unscoped (or singleton) bindings and Subcomp would be `@SomeScope`, providing all the `@SomeScope` bindings.

Comment: @Dino in short, an unscoped component can not have scoped modules. If you want to provide `@Singleton` you have to apply the same scope to the component. I don't know from the top of my head what then would happen to unscoped objects though

Comment: Ok, so this means that if I want to use Singleton scope and SomeScope, I will have to split the `@Provides` methods for the different scopes into different modules. It's not immediately obvious why this should be necessary implementation-wise, but I suppose that's just how it is :/

Comment: @Dino see the quote of the documentation: They intend you to have different lifecycles for different scopes :)

Comment: Yes, if the *modules* handle the lifetimes, then that makes sense. I guess I was originally hoping that the components handled the lifetimes, which would have left some hope for Subcomp to manage `@Foo` lifecycle even though the module is technically added to its parent component.